# Using both the cors package and setting Access-Control headers to no luck

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-400

Ok, so I'm having problems with the Access-Control headers. What's weird is that it worked for some time, and then suddenly stopped working, without me modifying the code. I'm sending a request from a react app that is running locally. The server I'm requesting is hosted on heroku and the error message I get is:

"Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Is there any errors in this code that is leading to this error?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Access-Token');
  next();
});
```

I captured the request:

```
Request URL:https://secret-server.herokuapp.com/levels/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:**.***.***.**:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:secret-server.herokuapp.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: We need to understand exactly what ajax request from what page is causing the cors error?  Also, if you're hosting on heroku, why are you doing `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: That makes sense! I'm sending a request from a react web app, do you know how I can capture the Ajax request to analyze it? The client is at http://localhost:3000, it is connected to the server at heroku, i.e. the server is refusing connections from my localhost

Comment: An ajax request to `http://localhost:3000` goes to the computer the browser is running on.  Is that really what you want?  You can see the ajax request in the network tab of the Chrome debugger?

Comment: I edited my question to involve the Ajax request

Comment: Probably failing the pre-flight options request.

Comment: @Darkrum do you know how to fix that? Shouldn't the cors package solve that automatically?

Comment: *Status Code:400 Bad Request* — that 400 failure response is the problem. It has nothing to do with the CORS config. The only reason you’re seeing mention of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in that browser error message on the client side is because your node server doesn’t add application-set headers to 400 failure responses — or any other 4xx or 5xx responses — it only adds them to 200 OK responses or other 2xx responses.

Comment: You should use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49089290/edit to edit/update the question to add/show the specific part of your frontend JavaScript code that’s making the request (that is, using XHR or fetch() or whatever Ajax library method you’re using). Because what your server is telling you with that 400 response is that the data you’re sending in the request is not what it expects to receive. So the handling of your request fails on the server side there, and the server is sending back that 400 message to tell you that it’s failed and you need to fix the request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting cors options this way:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  methods: ['GET','PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['X-Access-Token'],
  preflightContinue: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```